# Siemens se5940, Factory Reset? Reconfig?

Tags: router, gateway, t1

I have inherited a Siemens se5940 T1 gateway that I would like to reset and put into use. I have been looking around for a manual but I'm not having much luck. Is anyone aware of a manual that can be downloaded? I need to reset the unit and reconfigure it if anyone can provide any info, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r19757842-Siemens-SE5940-Router, in particular [this post](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r19783558-).

Comment: thanks for the info, managed to get it reset and connected. Web interface is ok but I would like to use the cli. Seems their commands are a bit different than Cisco's though, so I'm still looking for a manual...